# Filtering MSBuild log entries?

Tags: logging, filter, msbuild

The files created by MSBuild when /filelogger is enabled are verbose and not (IMHO) very useful. Specifically are there command line arguments (or a post-processor tool) for:

1. identifying only errors?
2. identifying 'compile' events such as CSC and VSCompile
3. Ditto linker/librarian invocations.

I'm porting .Net micro framework which has a very large number of interlinked .proj files and getting a clearer picture of exactly what is going on is rather difficult.

I have looked at both DependencyVisualizer, MSBuild Sidekick and MSBuildExplorer but they are not particularly helpful - though the latter would be if it recursively explored projects!

Comment: Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171470.aspx there is example of error only log in `Saving the log output to multiple files` section

Comment: Hello! Could you put the answer in an answer instead of putting it within the question body! Could you also remove the "solved" from the title! For more information see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered. Thank you for your help on keeping the site as consistent and clean as possible!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. However this path has been travelled by others, notably by the Wintellect team. See this blog for discussion and code for a fully featured custom logger that actually displays compiler error messages (!)

http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/01/17/smarter-logging-with-msbuild.aspx